# Foreign Key relation does not populate in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Using django 1.0.1 on windows xp and postgres database

I have a very strange problem in the Django admin page. Using the model and admin below, the field "balance" does populate with objects from the Balance model. However, it does NOT populate the locationparameter field: the name "locationparameter" does appear, but there is no pull-down menu.

History: the Balance, BalanceMember object is new and I just did a manage.py syncdb. LocationParameter did already exist in the system.

Manually creating a BalanceMember does work:

```
bm = BalanceMember.objects.create(balance=b, locationparameter=lp, type=1, function=1)
bm.save()
```

Anyone an idea where to look?

models.py:

```
class BalanceMember(models.Model):
     balance = models.ForeignKey(Balance)
     locationparameter = models.ForeignKey(LocationParameter)
     type = models.IntegerField()
     function = models.IntegerField()
```

admin.py

```
admin.site.register(BalanceMember)
```

Comment: Do all the relevant tables exist? Is the data in the database tables what you expect?

Comment: As far as I can see, yes.. report_balancemember has all the columns and constraints. I don't see why it shouldn't work for locationparameter. report_locationparameter and report_balance both exist.

Comment: I did restart postgres and apache, but not the computer

Answer (score 0):

try adding:
admin.site.register(LocationParameter)